# Compare two variables with generated numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Currently I learn the curve of PHP and for first time trying to make AJAX request to my PHP script. I got cart in my own written shop for learning purposes, it generates button and input field with same "data-id" attributes for each position. And of course, input field got "value" attribute with current amount of products.

Code:

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".btn").click(function () {
        var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
        var idInput = $(".field").attr("data-id");
        var value = $(".field").attr("value");
        if (id === idInput) {
            $.post("/cart/addAjax/" + id, {}, function (data) {
                $("#cart-count").html(data);
            });
            $.post("/cart/addAjax/" + value, {});
            return false;
        } else {}
    });
});
```

Example of input of PHP generated HTML:

```
            <input class="field" data-id="3" type="number" value="23">
            <button class="btn" data-id="3">Quantity</button>

            <input class="field" data-id="14" type="number" value="3">
            <button class="btn" data-id="14">Quantity</button>

            <input class="field" data-id="17" type="number" value="2">
            <button class="btn" data-id="17">Quantity</button>

            <input class="field" data-id="18" type="number" value="8">
            <button class="btn" data-id="18">Quantity</button>

            <input class="field" data-id="19" type="number" value="10">
            <button class="btn" data-id="19">Quantity</button>
```

I want Jquery script to compare input/button "data-id" attributes and send "value" of selected "data-id" attribute request to PHP side, but don't know how to tell script get "value" from selected "data-id", guess its the reason why its POST successfully only for first generated product in cart, for the rest products script doesn't work. Can someone enlighten me how to achieve this? Thanks in advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to structor your html a little better.

I made some changes to the html and put each `btn` and `field` under a div.

This will make things easer to find the selected input by its `btn click`.

Read the comment to understand.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".btn").click(function () {
        var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
        // now go to the selected btn Parent, and then find the .field
        // there you are sure its the right field becouse both the button       
        // and the field is containe under one div{Parent}
        var idInput = $(this).parent().find(".field")
       console.clear();
       console.log("you Selected id " +id + " and its value is " + idInput.val())
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>

            <input class="field" data-id="3" type="number" value="23">
            <button class="btn" data-id="3">Quantity</button>
  </div> 
  <div>
            <input class="field" data-id="14" type="number" value="3">
            <button class="btn" data-id="14">Quantity</button>
   </div>
   <div>
            <input class="field" data-id="17" type="number" value="2">
            <button class="btn" data-id="17">Quantity</button>
    </div>
    <div>
            <input class="field" data-id="18" type="number" value="8">
            <button class="btn" data-id="18">Quantity</button>
   <div>
            <input class="field" data-id="19" type="number" value="10">
            <button class="btn" data-id="19">Quantity</button>
   </div>
```

Comment: That's exactly what I lurked for, thanks. But I can't get this work on my project for some reason, can you take a look on on my pen? https://codepen.io/RedEclipse/pen/aXQYgb

Comment: That was silly me or kind of browser glitch, thanks again

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('button').on('click',function(){
  var data = $(this).data('id');
  var url = 'your php file';
  $.post(url,data,function(rdata){
    //do whatever yo want with returned data
  });
});
```

Comment: You forgot to send the value of the input field